# Issue with saving and retrieving array with sort by UserDefaults

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsuserdefaults

Hello  I am trying too add some `String` to the an `Array` and then store its values with `UserDefaults`, here is my code :

```
func addStored(urlString:String) {

        //Add URL to array and save it
        downloadedURLArray.append(urlString)

        UserDefaults.standard.set(downloadedURLArray, forKey: "storedURL")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

        var array = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "storedURL")  as? [String] ?? [String]()
        array = array.sorted { $0 < $1 }
        print(array.description)

    }
```

I am trying to retrieve its data in ascending or descending :

`array = array.sorted { $0 < $1 }`

But compiler give me wrong or even random!!! values for example I am adding these item to Array :

> A
>   B
>   C

The retrieved data is :

> B
>   C
>   A

What is wrong ? I am I sort the array in right way ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this  -- >.    array = array.sorted { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending

Answer (score 0):

Don't call the user defaults from inside the same function. Call it from another function or the `ViewDidLoad`.
Working Example:

```
var downloadedURLArray = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    addStored(urlString: "Kegham")
    addStored(urlString: "Sevan")
    addStored(urlString: "Ines")

    var array = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "storedURL")  as? [String] ?? [String]()
    array = array.reversed()
    print(array.description)   //output

}


func addStored(urlString:String) {

    //Add URL to array and save it
    downloadedURLArray.append(urlString)

    UserDefaults.standard.set(downloadedURLArray, forKey: "storedURL")

}
```

> The output is: ["Ines", "Sevan", "Kegham"]

Comment: There is no reason to call `synchronize`.

Comment: @rmaddy yes i think you are right. I was going to remove it.

Comment: Sorry but your output should be `Ines , Sevan , Kegham` , The problem still exists !

Comment: @Mc.Lover How come...? Letter "I"...then Letter "K"...then Letter "S"... how come my output should be the "S" before the "K"

Comment: NO ! I don't want to sort array alphabetical just its index change for example `1,2,3` to `3,2,1`

Comment: I found the solution `urlArray.reverse()` is the answer